# Get 24 hour average by time of day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

I have a simple table with DateTime "PostDate" and decimal "NumericValue".'

Each row has a timestamp with seconds.

If I do a standard 1440 minute average I get the average at midnight of each day. I would like to get the average for 24 hours at 7am between a date range. Like 1/1/2020 07:00:00 - 3/1/2020 07:00:00

Comment: Please add additional information directly into the question ([edit]), not as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can offset the datetime by 7 hours, then aggregate:

```
select
    cast(dateadd(hour, -7, postdate) as date) dy,
    avg(numericvalue) avg_value
from mytable
group by cast(dateadd(hour, -7, postdate) as date)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.